SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in appium
Getting the below error, working on a teammate's laptop so looks like there is no error in the code.  Maybe it's my local packages but not sure.
node version: v18.20.1
npm version : 10.5.0
import {
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:76:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1283:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1328:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:203:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async ConfigParser.addConfigFile (file:///Users/app-auto/node_modules/@wdio/config/build/lib/ConfigParser.js:85:36)


After updating below package the error has been resolved
    "@wdio/cli": "8.3.5",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "8.3.5",
---->
 "@wdio/cli": "8.35.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "8.35.1",

